# Fast bijective $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, algorithms

I am looking for a fast pairing function which maps two integers (cartesian coordinates) to a single unique integer. In other words, 
$$
\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z},
$$
thats has a one-to-one-correspondence (bijection).

I have found Cantor's pairing function, 
$$
f(x,y) = \frac{(x+y)\times(x+y+1)}{2}+y,
$$
which is,
$$
\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N},
$$
and a bijection, but since it is from $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ it only works for coordinates where x and y are both positive or zero.

Additionally I have found the 'elegant pairing function' written by [Matthew Szudzik](http://szudzik.com/ElegantPairing.pdf) which suffers from the same issue.

There should be a way to modify Cantor's, or Szudzik's method so that it spirals around (0,0) as opposed to saw toothing through all of the positive integer pairs.

Is such a function already defined?

If not is there a good place to start in creating one?

What about,
$$
\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}.
$$

Comment: What do you mean with defined? You can define the spiral, $f((0,0)=0$, $f((0,1))=1$, $f((1,1))=2$, $f((1,0))=3$, etc...

Comment: What would the function look like to have it spiral like that?

Comment: I think that ([tag:algorithms]) is an appropriate tag - since you are looking for somethings which works fast. (I suppose you means that there is a fast algorithm. Also ([tag:elementary-set-theory]) seems suitable to me, since bijections like this are studied in this area. I left there ([tag:number-theory]), which was your original tag. Feel free to retag, if you have better ideas. (Of course, anyone can retag, not only the OP.)

Answer (score 2):

Essentially all that is needed to turn a bijection $p:\Bbb{N}^2 \mapsto \Bbb{N}$ into a bijection $\Bbb{Z}^2\mapsto \Bbb{Z}$ is composition with a bijection $q: \Bbb{Z}\mapsto\Bbb{N}$. Several possible $q$'s exist, but a particularly easy to calculate one is $$q(n) = \begin{cases} 2n &n\ge 0 \\ -2n - 1 &n<0,\end{cases}$$ with inverse function $$q^{-1}(n) = \begin{cases} n/2 &n\cong 0\pmod 2 \\ -(n+1)/2 &n\cong 1 \pmod 2 .\\ \end{cases}$$

If you let $p$ be any of the pairing functions you've found from $\Bbb{N}^2 \mapsto \Bbb{N}$, then $q^{-1}(p(q(a),q(b))$ will bijectively map $\Bbb{Z}^2 \mapsto \Bbb{Z}$ (using $q$ to map the arguments into $\Bbb{N}$, then pairing with $p$ and going back to $\Bbb{Z}$ with $q^{-1}$.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, I hadn't thought of it. Its very straight forward to implement, and should be fairly fast. Though is there not a more 'elegant' approach? By this I mean without intermediary transformations, to make the single question a series of simpler questions.