# Need some hint for wrintg an explicit expression for f: N--> ZxZ bijective

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hey i will be happy to get some hint on how it can be done.
in class i saw an example on how it can be done by mapping it in a "spiral" way.
but i cant find an explicit function that works.
the numbering is(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1), (-1,1), (-1,0), (-1,-1), (0,-1), (1,-1),(2,-1), (2,0), (2,1) (2,2), (1,2), etc.

Comment: Minor variant of [Cardinality of the set of all pairs of integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187751/cardinality-of-the-set-of-all-pairs-of-integers)

Comment: Describing the spiral using words **is** an explicit function that works. Functional formulas are not always necessary, and I would argue in this case even directly unhelpful, as it is just going to be cluttered and difficult to read.

Comment: Unfortunately my professor don't thinks this way :(

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196451/bijection-from-mathbbz-to-mathbbz-times-mathbbz and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42942/how-can-i-index-2-dimensional-points-starting-at-the-origin-and-going-outwards and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521029/fast-bijective-mathbbz-times-mathbbz-rightarrow-mathbbz